# Value of the angle in isosceles triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I try to find a way to calculate value of one of the isosceles triangle angles when I have given values of its height `h = 200` and base `x = 200`. Values of those can vary depend on the condition, so I need an universal solution. I'll be very grateful for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a computer, you can say that

```
a = atan2(x/2, h)
```

Alternatively, you can use the simpler form

a = arctan(x/(2h))

If you type this into google, for particular values of $x$ and $h$, you'll get the answer you want. For instance, searching for

```
atan(100/200) in degrees
```

returned the answer

```
26.5650512 degrees
```

The query

```
atan(200/(2*200)) in degrees
```

produced the same thing.

---

A bit more detail.

Computing sine, cosine, and tangent isn't as easy as square root, but it's not insanely hard. It turns out that if you know $\tan(a)$ and $\tan(b)$ you can use "addition formulas" to compute $\tan(a \pm b)$ and $\tan(a/2)$. Starting from one known value, like 
$\tan(45^{\deg}) = 1$, you can compute many other values, enough to build a pretty complete table, and then fill in by interpolating. This takes time and energy, but that's life. Once you have a table of tangents, you can swap the columns to give you "inverse tangent" -- a function that says "what angle has this tangent?" That's called "arctan".

In fact, you can build an arctan table using addition rules as well, which is a bit more direct. Proving the addition laws? That's what trigonometry is all about.

It turns out that $\arctan(x)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $x$...but one with infinitely many terms. Fortunately, for small $x$, most of the terms are very small, so you can get away with evaluating just the first few (i.e., the larger) terms without making much error. This is in fact what the Java Math library's authors do, albeit in a somewhat more sophisticated way. The proof that arctan can be written as a polynomial comes up in calculus, under the general heading of "Approximation by Polynomials", or more specifically, "Taylor Series". Textbooks have multiple chapters about these, so I can't explain it all here, of course. Wish I could, but...

Comment: To be honest I asked this question in the context of Java, but I would like to know how this function is expressed mathematically. I would like to understand its basis.

Comment: See details added in question.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much. Time to go back to the maths' basics :)

Answer (score 0):

Using trigonometry, $a=\arctan(100/200)$.

Comment: I believe this should be $\arctan(100/200)$.

Comment: @JohnHughes - thanks. I've undeleted this since your post only discusses computing the number.